# Multi depth directory watcher using Poco

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

How can I create a multi depth directory watcher using POCO?

If it is primarily in **D:\ddd**, and we even go to **D:\ddd\d1\d2\d3\NewTextDoc.txt**, then also it should notify me.
I am able to do it for the initial directory only.
I used the event listeners and they notifies me if anything happens in the initial directory.

Here is my code that worked:

```
try
{
  AutoPtr<PropertyFileConfiguration> pConf = new 
  PropertyFileConfiguration("EventListener.properties");
  Poco::DirectoryWatcher dirWatcher(pConf->getString("path"), 
  Poco::DirectoryWatcher::DW_FILTER_ENABLE_ALL, 
  Poco::DirectoryWatcher::DW_DEFAULT_SCAN_INTERVAL);

  dirWatcher.itemModified       += Poco::delegate(this, &ClsDirWatcher::onFileModified);        //good
  dirWatcher.itemMovedFrom      += Poco::delegate(this, &ClsDirWatcher::onFileMovedFrom);       //no way, seems only linux
  dirWatcher.itemMovedTo        += Poco::delegate(this, &ClsDirWatcher::onFileMovedTo);         //no way, seems only linux
  dirWatcher.itemAdded          += Poco::delegate(this, &ClsDirWatcher::onFileAdded);           //working fine
  dirWatcher.itemRemoved        += Poco::delegate(this, &ClsDirWatcher::onFileRemoved);         //lol!!!

  waitForTerminationRequest();    
}
catch (Poco::Exception& exc)
{
  logger().log(exc);
}
```

Comment: Well, I understand that, I have to use threads that individually will hold the directories whenever a new one is created. Is that the way?

Comment: Well, there can be one parent thread and whenever a new directory is created, a thread will be there to monitor the directory. In such a way, we can form a recursive thread creation to monitor all the directories and sub-directories. But, the problem is, there will not be any master control to handle all the threads. 
I don't think this is a good design. Someone please suggest me the way.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. According to the [Poco documentation](https://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.DirectoryWatcher.html):

> Note that changes to files in subdirectories of the watched directory are not reported. Separate DirectoryWatcher objects must be created for these directories if they should be watched.

So what you need to do is spawn a new directory watcher for each existing subdirectory that you want to watch. You would also need to put some logic in the `itemAdded` delegate to spawn a new monitor if a new directory is created within a directory that you are monitoring.

Comment: This is not making sense. If poco is using the `inotify` kernel feature, then why its implementation in `DirectoryWatcher` sounds very complicated? You can run the `inotifywait` and it could recursively notify file system changes from a given directory recursively. Is poco doing a polling?